# Karma not running in Jenkins CI, Cannot find module 'karma-jasmine'

Tags: jenkins, karma-jasmine

I'm setting up an Angular 4 SPA with automatic testing in Jenkins CI. The SPA is part of a larger, Maven-managed project, so the build is also Maven-managed. So far I've:

1. Installed the NodeJS plugin on Jenkins, using install from nodejs.org with version 8.6.0
2. Configured "Global npm packages to install" = "karma-cli phantomjs-prebuilt jasmine-core karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-junit-reporter karma-coverage"
3. Added the "maven-karma-plugin" in pom.xml with browsers=PhantomJS / singleRun=true / reporters=dots,junit
4. Enabled "Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH" on the Jenkins job configuration

The build process starts up quite ok, but eventually I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-karma-plugin:1.6:start (default) @ webclient ---
[INFO] Executing Karma Test Suite ...
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/bin/karma start /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/funnel_build/webclient/karma.conf.js --browsers PhantomJS --reporters dots,junit --single-run
07 10 2017 17:07:52.801:ERROR [config]: Error in config file! 
 { Error: Cannot find module 'karma-jasmine' 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23) 
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17) 
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18) 
    at module.exports (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/funnel_build/webclient/karma.conf.js:9:7) 
    at Object.parseConfig (/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:410:5)
```

The npm install at the very beginning of the build logs:

```
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/bin/npm install -g karma-cli phantomjs-prebuilt jasmine-core karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-junit-reporter karma-coverage
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/bin/karma -> /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/bin/phantomjs -> /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.15 install /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

Considering PhantomJS found at /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/bin/phantomjs
Looks like an `npm install -g`
Could not link global install, skipping...
Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1507388835905/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node.js_8.6.0/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.0 requires a peer of karma@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-junit-reporter@1.2.0 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.4 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.

+ karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.4
+ karma-coverage@1.1.1
+ karma-jasmine@1.1.0
+ karma-cli@1.0.1
+ karma-junit-reporter@1.2.0
+ jasmine-core@2.8.0
+ phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.15
updated 7 packages in 10.553s
```

(The reason the package 'karma' is currently not on the list is that I read somewhere that karma-cli should be used in place of karma. Adding the 'karma' package doesn't change anything, however.)

Any idea why that "Cannot find module 'karma-jasmine'" pops up? In (2) you'll see that the karma-jasmine package is listed, I find it on the server, but still it's not found by the NodeJS plugin.

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by running "npm install" as part of the build process, and then run everything on local npm packages.

The entire setup is described here: https://funneltravel.wordpress.com/2017/10/16/running-karma-with-maven-on-jenkins-ci/